# C++11: How to parse a hex string from stringstream when leading character is alpha (abcdef)

Tags: c++, c++11, hex, stringstream

I am attempting to read a hex value from a std::stringstream based on the example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex. Everything works fine when the leading character of the string is a numeric character [0-9], but when the leading character is an alpha character [a-f,A-F] getting the value from the stream consumes the characters but doesn't assign a value to the integer. Is there a flag or something that needs to be set to tell stringstream or std::hex that this is, in fact, a valid hex value and should be interpreted as such?

I will probably just end up reading from the stream into a string and using std::stoi, but wondered why parsing directly from the stringstream doesn't work or if there is a way to make it work.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int anint = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str("1234abcd");
    ss >> std::hex >> anint;
    printf("anint = %x\n", anint);

    anint = 0;
    ss.str("a234abcd");
    ss >> std::hex >> anint;
    printf("anint = %x\n", anint);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
anint = 1234abcd
anint = 0
```

Comment: More generally this is also perhaps a lesson in the risks of re-using objects when you don't need to. My aesthetic/habit at the moment is such that I'd have put both tests inside their own block scope (i.e. add `{` and `}` around them) just as a matter of course. That completely prevents bugs/mistakes such as this.

Comment: Please don't fundamentally change the question after it's been answered. I have rolled back your edit. Thanks.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, thanks for the clarifications. It was meant to be a toy example so I didn't put as much effort into avoiding reusing variables as I should have initially. Hopefully this time I edited it better so that people can actually get help if they run into a similar problem.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Seems your rollback didn't stick around for long. Not sure what comes next?

Comment: @Jacob Asteroid With Wings rolled back your previous edit for a very good reason - so why have you just repeated it?

Comment: @AdrianMole. I left the original and only put the edits below or should what better produced my question go in a separate answer? I didn't repeat the edit, I did it a different way

Comment: Well, [this is what folks normally do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).when a helpful answer is given (though I'm not recommending one way or the other - it's up to you). The note on *"Turns out all I needed was to read an unsigned int"* would be OK as a comment (to the answer, probably).

Comment: @AdrianMole I give up and leave the OP to it.

Comment: _" It was meant to be a toy example so I didn't put as much effort into avoiding reusing variables as I should have initially."_ Yet that literally caused the problem. So always good to be on your guard :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It's my first question, so I'm trying to learn. Is it better to edit my post with better code to produce the root of the question, or put that somewhere else? How do I note the actual resolution which was to use an unsigned int?

Comment: @Jacob But you also needed to either call `clear` on your original stringstream (which will work, of course) or use a new one (which as the same effect). The use of unsigned int would be a follow-up to my comment about overflow.

Comment: @Jacob We have a whole answer section for answers/solutions. You can post one yourself to show what you ended up with :) If an existing answer made you realise you did something silly and you still have a [different] followup question, you can just post a new question to that effect.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWIngs Ok, I cleaned up the original so it's back to the way it was and posted an answer with what worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (main) problem in your code is that you are not clearing the `EOF` flag after your first read of the string stream! Also, if your system uses a 32-bit `int` type, the value `a234abcd` will overflow, and you'll (probably) get a value of `0x7FFFFFFF` (which is `INT_MAX`).

The following code gives what (I think) you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int anint = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str("1234abcd");
    ss >> std::hex >> anint;
    printf("anint = %x\n", anint);

    ss.clear(); // Clear EOF flag!
    anint = 0;
//  ss.str("a234abcd");// Will overflow 32-bit int!
    ss.str("a234abc"); // Works 'properly'
    ss >> std::hex >> anint;
    printf("anint = %x\n", anint);

    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: This. The test in the question is broken.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Indeed!  But what I can't find is a definitive reference as to why `ss >> std::hex >> anint` won't properly interpret the OP's original value as a negative number, rather than overflowing and giving `MAX_INT`.

Comment: Because it isn't a negative number.

Comment: Don't forget signed overflow is not a well-defined thing. It doesn't wrap around like unsigned values do. You may be putting too much faith in some practical symptoms of UB that you've seen in the past. The IOStream library is not designed to trigger UB. Flagging a value out of range _is_ "proper".

Comment: No, there's nothing odd about it. The OP's original value is not a negative number, so there is no reason to expect a negative number to be parsed from it.

Comment: I'll repeat to you the advice I gave to the OP: _check for errors_. Your `ss` will be in an error state after your attempted extraction, because _it failed_. _"If extraction fails, zero is written to `value` and `failbit` is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in `value`, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and `failbit` flag is set."_ [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: That the same error checking is not performed when you just assign to an `int` (instead you get signed overflow, which has undefined or unspecified behaviour) doesn't change that. Certainly expecting/relying on a negative value as a result in either case is wrong.

Comment: No, the hexadecimal representation of -1,573,606,451 is -0x5dcb5433. 0xa234abcd is a positive number (2,721,360,845).

Comment: Because you passed a `int` when `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. Your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's very common to think in terms of "32 bits" and "0xFFFFFFFF is negative" when dealing with hexadecimal representations because people have been mistaught/mislead by actual _decades_ of relying on signed overflow and making assumptions about the results. But it just isn't true. Positive numbers are positive numbers, and negative numbers are negative numbers, no matter what base you're in.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Maybe consider cleaning up the comments here?

Comment: Hmm the answer still contains some falsehoods though that are explored in the comments

Comment: Turns out what I needed was to use an unsigned int. Comments helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code like @Adrian Mole mentioned and now I'm seeing results that make more sense. Turns out all I needed was to read an unsigned int.

Edited Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int anint1 = 0;
    std::stringstream ss1;
    ss1.str("1234abcd");
    ss1 >> std::hex >> anint1;
    printf("anint = %x\n", anint1);

    int anint2 = 0;
    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss2.str("a234abcd");
    ss2 >> std::hex >> anint2;
    printf("anint = %x\n", anint2);

    unsigned int anunint = 0;
    std::stringstream ss3;
    ss3.str("a234abcd");
    ss3 >> std::hex >> anunint;
    printf("anunint = %x\n", anunint);

    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
anint = 1234abcd
anint = 7fffffff
anunint = a234abcd
```